# jupyter notebook resize plot to full cell width

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'd like to plot a line graph (in python) and have the plot size be set to the full width of the cell of the jupyter or jupyterlab notebook.  (Also, if the cell width changes I'd like to be notified and have the opportunity to change the plot size)

I am aware of `matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (x, y)` , but what do I set x and y to? Is the cell width discoverable ?

Comment: Do you have `seaborn` installed?  If so you could use `sns.set_context('talk')` or `sns.set_context('poster')` to easily change the figure size although this doesn't answer your question.